# Добавление элемента после элемента

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте, прошу помочь, начал учить js и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, у меня есть кнопка:

```
<button id = "add_post">Добавить Сообщение</button>
```

Ловлю я значит событие onclick:

```
add_post = document.getElementById('add_post');
add_post.onclick = function() {
  // А вот тут мне нужно добавить после кнопки допустим input`ы 
  // Делал так: add_post.innerHTML +='<input type = "text" name = "title" placeholder      = "Заголовок">';
  // Думал заработает, оказалось, что когда я обращаюсь при помощи innerHTML к баттону, он просто изменяет содержимое между <button>тут</button>

}
```

Сразу говорю гуглил, но  ничего решения не нашёл

Answer (score 1):

Будет работать, в случае если в родителе только одна кнопка. Ну и после этой кнопки уже добавляется какой либо HTML код.

Для таких целей лучше все же использовать jQuery, все на много удобнее и быстрее. Но как для обучения примерчик годится думаю.

```
<script>
    function add(){
        var btn = document.getElementById('add_post');
        var wrap = btn.parentNode;
        wrap.innerHTML += '<input type="text">';
    }
</script>

<div>
    <button id = "add_post" onclick = "add()">Добавить Сообщение</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/KkJZv/
http://jsfiddle.net/UMq5f/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/2cmeZ/

По клику создаю объект, добавляю атрибуты и делаю appendChild.

Comment: Версия 2.0, если нужно добавить только 1 input.

http://jsfiddle.net/2cmeZ/

Comment: Ну тогда и версия 3.0 
http://jsfiddle.net/KkJZv/